# How to search all list elements?

Tags: python

```
my_dict={'reportName': 'sale_order', 'extract_extractType': 'sales',  'extract_stages_load_output_tableName': 'extract_table_name',
'extract_stages_load_clientMarket_tableFilters_0': 'client_mkt_version_id|1', 
'extract_stages_load_clientMarket_tableFilters_1': 'client_mkt_short_name|HCV_NOVEL', 
'extract_stages_load_clientMarket_tableFilters_2': 'client_Id|161'}

case1:
kv=['extract', 'output']
```

Now my question is if all list elements present on dictionary then display key and value and dict.

output: `'extract_stages_load_output_tableName': 'extract_table_name'`.

case2:
if list elements contains **tableFilters**
kv=['extract','clientMarket','tableFilters','client_mkt_short_name']
output: 'extract_stages_load_clientMarket_tableFilters_1': HCV_NOVEL

same way for remaining
{'extract_stages_load_clientMarket_tableFilters_0': 1,
'extract_stages_load_clientMarket_tableFilters_1': 'HCV_NOVEL',
'extract_stages_load_clientMarket_tableFilters_2': 161'}

Comment: Do you mean if all the strings in `kv` are present in a *dictionary key*?

Comment: yes based on kv all list elements present then need to get key and value

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In case you are not searching for specific words in underscore-separted strings:

```
my_dict={'reportName': 'sale_order', 'extract_extractType': 'sales',
         'extract_stages_load_output_tableName': 'extract_table_name', 'numeric_value': 10}
kv=['extract', 'output']


for key, value in my_dict.items():
    if isinstance(value, str):  # in case value is not a string
        kv_string = key + '|' + value
        contains = True
        for item in kv:
            if kv_string.find(item) == -1:
                contains = False
        if contains:
            print(f"{key}: {value}")

    else:
        print("-w: non-string value in dict")
```

Comment: @JashwanthCH don't forget to mark one of the answers as right

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_key(key, kv):
    return len(set(kv) - set(key.split('_'))) == 0

{k: v for k, v in my_dict.items() if get_key(k, kv)}
{'extract_stages_load_output_tableName': 'extract_table_name'}
```

Edit

```
def get_key(key, kv):
    return all([_kv in s for _kv in kv])

{k: v for k, v in my_dict.items() if get_key(k, kv)}
{'extract_stages_load_output_tableName': 'extract_table_name'}
```

Comment: That's OK if the dict key always contains underscore between terms.

Comment: No need to use `len` just use `not`

Comment: @jarmond Made an edit

Comment: @Jab Thanks, I was looking at how to do that but couldn't find it.